# Intent does not work in Android notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I try to make notification, but click on notification does not work as expected: in activity I could not retrive additional info send in notification:

```
    int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoadPictureActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Test", "sometext");
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestID, intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_signin_btn_icon_focus_light)
                    .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(msg))
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

In LoadPictureActivity`s onCreate method I try to catch additional info:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Log.d("App", "Intent get intent: " + intent);
    if (intent != null) {
        Log.d("App", "Intent extra sting: " + intent.getStringExtra("Test"));
    }
}
```

But after click on notification I do not see any output with additional string, I also try to put the same check in OnResume, but in this case after click on notification I see that fires the intent that original start main class with nullable extra string. So I'm not sure if notification click works correctly in total. Where is the problem?

Comment: Sounds to me like you are using a special launch mode (like `singleTask` or `singleInstance`, in which case, when you tap the `Notification`, `onCreate()` isn't being called at all. Android is just resuming the existing instance of your `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```